# Изменение данных столбца одного датафрейма, на основе данных из другого датафрейма по условию

Tags: dataframe, сравнение

Коллеги. Пожалуйста помогите решить вопрос.
Имеем 2 датафрейма -

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame({'code': '100 101 102 103 104'.split(),
                   'fruit': 'fruit_1 fruit_2 fruit_3 fruit_4 fruit_5'.split(),
                   'quantity': '7 3 0 1 0'.split()})
```

и

```
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({'code': '102 100 104'.split(), 'fruit': 'fruit_3 fruit_1 fruit_5'.split(), 'quantity': '10 10 10'.split()})
```

Которые выглядят соответственно так:

df1:

```
    code     fruit      quantity
0   100     fruit_1        7
1   101     fruit_2        3
2   102     fruit_3        0
3   103     fruit_4        1
4   104     fruit_5        0
```

и

df2:

```
    code    fruit       quantity
0   102     fruit_3       10
1   100     fruit_1       10
2   104     fruit_5       10
```

Задача:

```
df1['quantity'] = df1['quantity'] + df2['quantity'] 

при условии, что 

df1['code'] = df2['code']
```

То есть, весь смысл задачи в том, чтобы при совпадении code (кода товара)
добавить к количеству этого товара df1['quantity'] количество соответствующего товара в df2['quantity'].

После выполнения задачи, df1 должен выглядеть так:

df1:

```
    code     fruit      quantity
0   100     fruit_1        17 (7+10)
1   101     fruit_2        3  (без изменений)
2   102     fruit_3        10 (0+10)
3   103     fruit_4        1  (без изменений)
4   104     fruit_5        10 (0+10)
```

Пока вопрос я решил только частично. Строка ниже делает выборку из df1,
если товар с соответствующим кодом есть в df2:

```
df1['code'].loc[df1['code'].isin(df2['code'])]
```

Осталось только для отобранных товаров в df1 изменить количество, прибавив его из df2.

Вот тут не могу найти ответ уже несколько дней.

Очень благодарен сообществу за помощь.

Comment: Ничего не понятно из вашего вопроса

Comment: Задачу уточнил и расписал подробнее

Comment: а от сообщества вы чего хотите? у вас код какой-то есть, наработки какие-то?

Comment: Да, добавил строку, которую удалось пока сделать. Дальше упёрся в стену.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос сам решил довольно просто. С помощью merge объединяем оба датафрейма по условию code:

```
df1 = (df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on=['code'], suffixes=['', '_new'], indicator='exists'))
```

Далее просто очищаем результат от пустых значений:

```
df1['quantity_new'].replace(np.nan, 0, inplace=True)
```

А также, на всякий случай:

```
df1['quantity_new'].replace('', 0, inplace=True)
```

Складываем искомые количества:

```
df1['quantity'] = df1['quantity'] + df1['quantity_new']
```

Удаляем ненужные столбцы:

```
df1.drop(['fruit_new', 'quantity_new', 'exists'], axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

Удачи в решении подобных задач!